# Variable value changing with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code what I want to do is to trigger one function with scroll which should be triggered on

```
if (flg == 0)
```

but if scroll did not happened till 5 sec, this other function will trigger with `setTimeout` and it will change variable `flg` value to `1` and scroll function should break but its not working.

`setTimeout` is updating variable value to 1 but I don't know why scroll function is working even though `flg` is 1.

```
$(function() {
    var flg = 0;
    //Image Load if Not Scroll ---------------------------
    var timer = setTimeout(function() {
        flg = 1;
        console.log (flg + 'change with timer');
    }, 5000);

    //Image Load On Scroll-----------
    if (flg == 0) {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            flg = 1;
            console.log (flg + 'srsc');
        });
    };
});
```

Example https://jsfiddle.net/0p1rob1q/1/

Comment: It sounds like logic error in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the `if` statement *inside* your window `scroll` event handler:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (flg == 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        ...
    }
});
```

You also need to remove the keyword `var` when overriding your initial `flg` value, otherwise it will not affect the global value and instead create a new local variable.

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0p1rob1q/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` needs to be inside the scroll function.
The way it is set up right now, it's checking the value of `flg` when it assigns the callback. Instead it should check it as needed:

```
$(window).scroll(function abc() {
    if (flg === 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        flg = 1;
        console.log(flg + 'srsc');
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9dwyjrnh/